# Are there any major disadvantages of having very large classes in CodeIgniter Controllers?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am building an App in CodeIgniter. I have a controller API and then It has got around 300 functions.

I wonder if this is an issue in terms of performance. Any body can help ?

Comment: It's an issue of maintenance primarily

Comment: Becomes an issue for a code editor before on php parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very large controller would take longer to parse. Every time any method from your Controller is called, the controller class is invoked and instantiated and thus the entire controller has to be parsed (Better put, the fat controller needs to be parsed in its entirity once per request). Parsing a larger file will take longer, however the additional time will be very minute.

This is the only disadvantage I can think of in terms of performance.

There are, of course, a host of maintenance issues.

**Explanation of  'Class in instantiated every time you call one of its methods'**

URL routing in CodeIgniter works this way:

`example.com/controller/method`

So when you visit

`example.com/user/create`

`create` is a function in the controller class `user`. To call the `create` method,`user` class has to first be instantiated, and then the method is called.

If your controller class has 200 other functions, they need to be parsed as well.

If you now point your browser to

`example.com/user/delete`

The previous instantiation of the class no longer exists. The entire class needs to be parsed again.

Comment: What do you mean the class is instantiated every time you call one of its methods?

Comment: Yeah but I can still call more than one method per request and it won't cause a reinstatiation of the class. In codeigniter, almost all methods are on the controller (`$this->whatever()`, and so on), it would be crazy

Comment: Yes, in that case the class won't be reinstantiated. Perhaps,a better wording of my initial answer would have been 'a class is instantiated once per request'.

Comment: Yes, but if you split a 200 function controller into ten different 20 function controllers, the amount of parsing per request is now one-tenth (assuming equal sized functions). However, as I mentioned in my answer, this is a very minor optimization.

Comment: Yeah I realized that just as I submitted my comment :P